# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment state change listener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, bottom-sheet

I'm using `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and I need to know, when the state changed.

For example there are states of `BottomSheetBehavior`

```
PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO - Peek at the 16:9 ratio keyline of its parent.    
STATE_COLLAPSED - The bottom sheet is collapsed.
STATE_DRAGGING - The bottom sheet is dragging.
STATE_EXPANDED - The bottom sheet is expanded.
STATE_HIDDEN - The bottom sheet is hidden.
STATE_SETTLING - The bottom sheet is settling.
```

I would like to change some Views based on current state - for example when the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` will be expanded full screen, I want to show cross icon on top right corner for closing it etc..

How I can listen to this kind of events?

Answer (score 0):

late, but probably the answer for Your question. You have to use the bottomSheetBehavior Callback.

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
  switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                    Log.d("Bottom Sheet Behavior", "STATE_COLLAPSED");
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                    Log.d("Bottom Sheet Behavior", "STATE_DRAGGING");
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                    Log.d("Bottom Sheet Behavior", "STATE_EXPANDED");

                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    Log.d("Bottom Sheet Behavior", "STATE_HIDDEN");
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                    Log.d("Bottom Sheet Behavior", "STATE_SETTLING");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no `bottomSheetBehavior` for `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Please let me know with some code example if I'm wrong.

Comment: not bad answer, if one know how to hack this.

Comment: `setBottomSheetCallback` is now deprecated. Use `addBottomSheetCallback` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `BottomSheetBehaviour` from the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, you have to use `BottomSheetDialogFragment.from(yourView)` in the `onCreateView` method of your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Result (Kotlin) :

```kotlin
class MyFragment() : BottomSheetDialogFragment()
{
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
        var result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bitmap, container, false)
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(result)
            .addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback()
                                    {

                                        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View,
                                                                    newState: Int)
                                        {
                                            // Here
                                        }

                                        override fun onSlide(p0: View, p1: Float)
                                        {
                                            //
                                        }
                                    })
        return result
    }
}
```